# Permission node in Android manifest does not have protectionLevel value, what's the value?

Tags: android

I noticed a  node in the Android manifest for one of the emulated devices using Android L/5.0 does not have a defined protectionLevel value.

```
<permission
    android:label="@android:01040228"
    android:name="android.permission.BODY_SENSORS"
    android:permissionGroup="android.permission-group.PERSONAL_INFO"
    android:description="@android:01040229"
    >
</permission>
```

The question is, what is the protectionLevel value of this permission?
Is it safe to assume the default protectionLevel value of any permission set to 0 - Normal if it's missing or unknown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation for the [`<permission>`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/permission-element.html) tag:

```
"normal"
```

---

> The default value. A lower-risk permission that gives requesting applications access to isolated application-level features, with minimal risk to other applications, the system, or the user. The system automatically grants this type of permission to a requesting application at installation, without asking for the user's explicit approval (though the user always has the option to review these permissions before installing).

Comment: I scanned the documentation section again and found that too.   I needed confirmation.  So that means the ProtectionLevel declaration is optional if the value is 0 - Normal.  I just think leaving it undeclared is not very good practice.  It's the only node I found in the Android Manifest that did not have a protectionLevel set.  Thank you for your confirmation.